# Error android compile - Error while launching activity

Tags: android

I made a small application that opened the html file.
Everything worked.

Today I wanted to add a code to check the internet connection and unfortunately after the code I have an error.

I'm using an android studio.

Error after compilation:
02/12 21:03:08: Launching app
Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity

Code MainActivity.java:

```
    package pl.mgraphic.myapplication;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Network;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView myBrowser;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
        myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");

        if(haveNetwork())
        {

        }
        else if (!haveNetwork())
        {
            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Please connect NETWORK!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    private boolean haveNetwork() {
        boolean have_WIFI = false;
        boolean have_MobileData = false;

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();

        for (NetworkInfo info : networkInfos) {
            if (info.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (info.isConnected())
                    have_WIFI = true;
            if (info.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MobileData"))
                if (info.isConnected())
                    have_MobileData = true;
        }
        return have_MobileData || have_WIFI;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post full manifest?

Comment: yes,post your `Manifest` and `activity_main.xml` to demonstrate your Question

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Check the presence of those `intent-filters` inside your `Activity` declaration.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

If this information is there, maybe some cache problem occured. Then, try this:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

Comment: Only now is another problem.
The application starts on the phone and immediately turns off.
I have wifi or mobile internet turned on.